# How to properly write the return type by looking at the Trait definition in rust

Tags: rust, nickel

I am having wrapping my head around how to figure out the return type of a function when I try to wrap them in other function.

I sometimes use a work-around, where I have a struct with the fields representing what I would pass if I could write the enclosing parent function. But that doesn't work properly.

Presently I am trying to use any of the routing frameworks, like nickel/tide. All of them have middleware support.

Taking nickel as example (because the interface looks easy), a simple middleware looks like this:

```rust
fn logger_fn(req: &mut Request, res: Response) -> MiddlewareResult {
    println!("logging request from logger fn: {:?}", req.origin.uri());
    res.next_middleware()
}
```

and in the [docs](https://docs.rs/nickel/0.11.0/src/nickel/middleware.rs.html#25-29) I can see the `impl` for the `trait`.

All I want is to wrap it in a function. In other language like golang I would write something like:

```
func ParentFunction() func(r Request, w Response) MiddlewareResult {
  return func (r Request, w Response) MiddlewareResult {...}
}
```

But in this case I am not able to figure out what to put the return value as.

I tried this:

```rust
fn add_header(is_internal: bool)-> Fn(&'r mut Request<'mw, 'conn, D>, Response<'mw, D>) -> MiddlewareResult<'mw, D> { 
    fn middleware_1(req: &mut Request, res: Response) -> MiddlewareResult {
        if is_internal {
            println!("internal");
            return res.next_middleware()
        }

        let auth_header = match req.origin.headers.get::<Authorization<Bearer>>() {
            Some(header) => header,
            None => panic!("No authorization header found")
        };

        let header = header::HeaderFormatter(auth_header).to_string();
        println!("Header v {}", header);
        res.next_middleware()
    }
}
```

and I get error messages:

```
help: consider making the bound lifetime-generic with a new `'conn` lifetime
  |
4 | fn add_header(is_internal: bool)-> for<'conn> Fn(&'r mut Request<'mw, 'conn, D>, Response<'mw, D>) -> MiddlewareResult<'mw, D> {
  |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'mw`
 --> src/main.rs:4:80
  |
4 | fn add_header(is_internal: bool)-> Fn(&'r mut Request<'mw, 'conn, D>, Response<'mw, D>) -> MiddlewareResult<'mw, D> {
  |                                                                                ^^^ undeclared lifetime
  |
  = note: for more information on higher-ranked polymorphism, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html
help: consider introducing lifetime `'mw` here
  |
4 | fn add_header<'mw>(is_internal: bool)-> Fn(&'r mut Request<'mw, 'conn, D>, Response<'mw, D>) -> MiddlewareResult<'mw, D> {
  |              ^^^^^
help: consider making the bound lifetime-generic with a new `'mw` lifetime
  |
```

which makes sense because I don't know how to use those lifetime variables and what to replace D with.

And this across whatever library I use. I am not able to understand this part of the language.

I need some assistance on how to do this, figuring out the return type.

Answer (score 2):

what your looking for is called closure but what you actualy want to return is an object that implement **Middleware**.

Also **Nickel** library has a utility macro called [middleware](https://docs.rs/nickel/0.11.0/nickel/macro.middleware.html) to make sure your macro implements the **Middleware** trait, without it there is a lot of boilerplate code to write.

Here a code snippet that sould work:

```rust
fn add_header<D>(is_internal: bool) -> impl Middleware<D> {
    middleware! { |req, res| 
        if is_internal {
            println!("internal");
            return res.next_middleware()
        }

        let auth_header = match req.origin.headers.get::<Authorization<Bearer>>() {
            Some(header) => header,
            None => panic!("No authorization header found")
        };

        let header = header::HeaderFormatter(auth_header).to_string();
        println!("Header v {}", header);
    }
}
```

I recommend you to read the rust book about closure for more information:
[Closures: Anonymous Functions that Can Capture Their Environment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html)
There is information about a keyword called **move** that is important when using  this type.